# jax-rs web service can't connect in to database using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jax-rs

I got error like this what can do for it?

type Exception report

> message
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not open connection
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.

exception

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not open connection
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not open connection
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:515)
>     org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getCustomer(Unknown Source)
>     com.resteasy.series.spring.hibernate.service.CustomerServiceImpl.getCustomerInfo(CustomerServiceImpl.java:33)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not open connection
>     org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
>     org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:427)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:429)
>     org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getCustomer(Unknown Source)
>     com.resteasy.series.spring.hibernate.service.CustomerServiceImpl.getCustomerInfo(CustomerServiceImpl.java:33)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   database 'benchresources'
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1747)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1287)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2494)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2527)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2309)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:419)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
>     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
>     org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
>     org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
>     org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:427)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:429)
>     org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
>     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getCustomer(Unknown Source)
>     com.resteasy.series.spring.hibernate.service.CustomerServiceImpl.getCustomerInfo(CustomerServiceImpl.java:33)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.23 logs.

Comment: Well, what can you tell us about DB `benchresources`? Does it exist for starters?

Comment: I try to create sample project using eclipse. I get resource form http://www.benchresources.net/resteasy-jax-rs-web-service-integrating-with-spring-and-hibernate-orm-framework/ that web site, but I can't get result in database..

Comment: The stack tells us it cannot connect to `benchresources`. You need to make sure that is available.

Comment: Any way, I don't know about **benchresources** . I got this http://www.benchresources.net/, please help me get data in database using Hibernate and Jax-rs web service. I also use Spring in this scenario.

Comment: You first need to create a DB to get your data into. Then you need to make sure your configuration/code is updated to use that DB.

Comment: I already update DB manually, but can't get data from DB. I do all thing that web site can't update data base. http://localhost:8080/RestEasy-Spring-Hibernate/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/10001 I try using that restfull URL but i can't get DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your hibernate.cfg.xml, check for the following property,

`property name="hibernate.connection.url"
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/benchresources
property`

If it exists then create a database in MySql(if you're using mysql) with the name 'benchresources'

Comment: 'property name="hibernate.connection.url"
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{myDBname}
property' I try it cant get data http://localhost:8080/RestEasy-Spring-Hibernate/resteasy/customerservice/getcustomer/10001 URL using,

Comment: '{mytDBname}' should be relpaced by the name of the DB you have created

Comment: I do like that, but can't update DB why? can't update DB I want know about it. my operating system as use Ubuntu, is this problem use Ubuntu.?